# Password-Protected Notes Encryption

Tags: encryption

I have one question about the encryption algorithm used for password-protected notes.

I am an Android smartphone user and for taking notes, I use my phone's native Samsung's note taking App.

But, I don't know what encryption algorithm it is used with Samsung's note taking App (password-protected notes).
Does anyone know what is the encryption algorithm?

Please let me know.
Thank You

Comment: In the decompiled source code there I can see `AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding` but Note supports multiple storage versions and I am not sure if this cipher belongs to the latest version. The used key seems to be generated using the user password and a native method in library `SNBConverter`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I do appreciate it.